# Alternating Axis Labeling between Left and Right Axis

Tags: plotting, import, ticks

I'm using the following to label a MatrixPlot:

`FrameTicks -> {{yticks, None}, {None, xticks}},`

I'm labeling these ticks with text. It is impossible to get the graph to a reasonable size while maintaining legibility of the text all on a single axis.

So what I'm attempting to do is sub-divide my label list, alternating the label that goes to one of two tick expressions:

`FrameTicks -> {{leftyticks, rightyticks}, {None, xticks}},`

But I have no idea how to do that. As of right now I am sorting the labels alternatively by hand and pasting them in to 'leftyticks' and 'rightyticks'. There has got to be a faster way to drag a list from a file, split it in alternating sequence, and dump the products in to the two tick-label groups, right?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, something like this will work:

```
labels = CharacterRange["a", "z"]; (* fake labels a, b, .. z *)
yticks = MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, labels]; (* {{1, a}, {2, b}, ..} *)

leftyticks = yticks[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]];
rightyticks = yticks[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]];
MatrixPlot[RandomReal[1, {26, 26}], 
 FrameTicks -> {{leftyticks, rightyticks}, {None, None}}]
```

[image: MatixPlot]

The main thing to note is that the `yticks` list has the form *{{y<sub>1</sub>, label<sub>1</sub>},{y<sub>2</sub>, label<sub>2</sub>}, ..}*. See the documentation for `Ticks`.

Comment: I was unable to upvote this due to my low user score, but this helped a lot! Thanks!

Comment: No worries.. you might be able to accept the answer though (if this solves your problem) by clicking on the check-mark below the votes counter.